# Using result of find command as input in scp to backup a remote server to my local machine

Tags: linux, ssh, find, pipe, scp

I have jenkins on a remote machine and the pipeline scripts are saved in the path `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs` in .xml format files. I can easily list the .xml files that are in that folder with this command:

`find /var/lib/jenkins/jobs -name config.xml`

which results in:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/productA/config.xml
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/productB/config.xml
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/productC/config.xml
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/productD/config.xml
/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/productE/config.xml
```

From my local machine I have already managed to make the recursive copy of the folder in remote machine (Remote File to a Local Machine):

```bash
scp -r jenkins@192.168.1.10:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/ /mnt/c/backupJenkins/
```

**What I would like to do is make a find that I described at the beginning of the question to use as input in `scp`.**

[There is a question that has already been asked here on the forum very similar](https://superuser.com/a/469590), but the find command it uses on the local machine to transfer to remote:

```bash
scp --exec=`find <path> -name <expression>` user@host:<path_where_to_copy>
```

---

Here some attempts I've already made based on my internet research that I also adapted, but they didn't work:

```bash
scp jenkins@192.168.1.10:$`find /var/lib/jenkins/jobs -name config.xml` /mnt/c/backupJenkins
```

```bash
for f in `find /var/lib/jenkins/jobs -name config.xml` ; do 
scp jenkins@192.168.1.10/$f /mnt/c/backupJenkins
done
```

---

An scp command looks like this:

```
scp [other options] [source username@IP]:/[directory and file name] [destination username@IP]:/[destination directory]
```

In 'other options' I think that passing the `-p` parameter would even be able to maintain the folder structure

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just ssh into the remote sever first? If you were on the remote, your 2nd attempt would be close to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can´t make work with a single command, but with two it worked

**Command A: `ssh jenkins@192.168.1.10 'cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs; find . -name config.xml ! -path '*/backup*' | rsync -avz --files-from=- . ./backup'`**

`'cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs;` - After ssh on my remote machine, I change directory to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs

`find . -name config.xml ! -path '*/backup*'` - Then make find and exclude the path of folder '/backup', this prevent rsync to copy 'backup' folder recursively.

`rsync --files-from=- SRC/ DST/` using this format for the rsync command we add the parameters `-avz` and `--files-from=-`

`| rsync -avz --files-from=- . ./backup'` - The single dash - filename here means STDIN, and this is a common convention among unix tools

The command B we just use rsync to copy a File from a Remote Server to a Local Server with SSH, and save on my local machine on new folder DAY-MONTH-YEAR ( /mnt/c/backupJenkins/$(/bin/date +%d-%m-%Y) )

**Command B: `rsync -avz jenkins@192.168.1.10:/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/backup/* /mnt/c/backupJenkins/$(/bin/date +%d-%m-%Y)`**